# Call instance function of a contract from embark console

Tags: solidity, web3js, testrpc, embark

I was following [this](https://ethereumdev.io/deploying-contract-embark-framework/) tutorial.I have deployed the following two contracts on testrpc:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract MDBService {

    mapping (address => address) accounts;
    mapping (uint => address) ids;
    uint numberAccounts;

    function MDBService() {
        numberAccounts = 0;
    }

    function register() {
        require(accounts[msg.sender] == 0); //We check if the user is already registered
        ids[numberAccounts] = msg.sender;
        accounts[msg.sender] = new MDBAccount(msg.sender);
        numberAccounts++;
    }
}

contract MDBAccount {

    struct Post {
        uint timestamp;
        string message;
    }

    uint public numberPosts;
    address public owner;
    mapping (uint => Post) posts;

    modifier isOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function MDBAccount(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
        numberPosts = 0;
    }

    function post(string message) isOwner() {
        require(bytes(message).length <= 160);
        posts[numberPosts].timestamp = now;
        posts[numberPosts].message = message;
        numberPosts++;
    }
}
```

Now when I call

```
MDBService.register({gas:700000,from:web3.eth.accounts[1]})
```

a new instance of MDBAccount is created(i.e. a new account MDBAccount for the user with address of account[1]).So now I want to post a message from this account instead of the default account[0].

When I call

```
MDBAccount.post('Hello')
```

it works because it uses the instance created when the contract deployed.But when I use

```
MDBAccount.post('Hello',{from:web3.eth.accounts[1]})
```

it fails because isOwner is not satisfied as it is using the same instance and not the one created on calling the above register.So how can I call post for account[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I call post for `accounts[1]`.

1. Remove `isOwner()` modifier

or

2. Initiate contract and send `accounts[1]` in parameter.

or

3. Add multiple owners

---

This is what this modifier is for, it restricts other addresses from calling functions which they should not call.

---

In your particular case I suggest to add address `_owner` directly to your struct `Post`. When you will need to retrieve only the posts of particular account, you will just filter them by `post._owner`.

```
struct Post {
        uint timestamp;
        string message;
        address _owner;
    }
```

Comment: Any of them won't work because what I want is like twitter where there is a separate account for each user and each user has his own tweets separated from each other stored only in their account.When I send account address in parameter than the post should be saved in the account of that address only.

Comment: Well then I suggest you to add `address _owner` directly to your struct `Post`. When you will need to retrieve only the posts of particular account, you will just filter them by `post._owner`. Another way is to use events, but in this case events will be visible **only** outside Solidity.

Comment: Adding _owner to struct Post is a really good alternative.Thanks. Add this as the answer and I will accept it as right.

Comment: @HimanshuChandra Edited the answer.